# Can DBSCAN be applied on clustering Strings, If so how it can be done?

Tags: data-mining, cluster-analysis, non-clustered-index, dbscan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply DBSCAN algorithm on grouping of similar url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422576/how-to-apply-dbscan-algorithm-on-grouping-of-similar-url)

I have been told to do a project in my final sem, as the project involves in clustering similar strings using DBSCAN. I want to know can this be done using DBSCAN, If yes then how can i implement the same.

Comment: What type of strings are we talking about? Long articles? Short snippets? Single words? What characters can be in the strings? I'm really tempted to close this as a too broad question (questions here should be practical, well-scoped problems), but I really like the subject so please clarify as much as you can.

Comment: yes Sir, Strings in the sense it can be part of a word or even a word both can be done for eg. www.sss.com and www.ddd.com here both end with com so I want to group these type of URLs and other with domain ext. org can be grouped. and rest be considered as noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you earlier (at [How to apply DBSCAN algorithm on grouping of similar url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422576/how-to-apply-dbscan-algorithm-on-grouping-of-similar-url) ), this is possible.

But **YOU** need to define the similarity you need for your application.

Nobody on stackoverflow will be able to help you with that, unless you are *very* clear on what kind of similarity you need.

There are lots of string metrics available, and **you** need to find out what works for **your** particular problem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric

Comment: Sir, I have very well told you abt the type of similarity I need (2nd comment above). Thank you for the link. This wud not let me post another question of same type.

Comment: You have not told us *way enough*. It is much too imprecise. In particular, what type of similarities you have **tried** so far.